# Flex/Air : Text Area with Line Number Filtering

Tags: apache-flex, air, textarea, filtering, line-numbers

I need to have a Text Area With Line Numbers,
& once the Text File is Imported to the Text Area..
the user must be able to select the line numbers & see the filtered output.

I have implemented the same with Numeric steppers.
I am in search of an enhanced component.

are there better Advanced Components for Textarea ?
Any Advanced Textarea component with built-in Search/Replace/Filter Capabilities ?

Cheers,
Ajay

Answer (score 0):

What do you consider to be a line? Do you need to take the line wrapping of the text area into consideration when you are selecting the lines, or are you only interested in the actual line characters in the underlying string?

If the latter applies, the you can probably accomplish what you want like this:

```
protected var selectedLineIndexes:Array = []; // of ints

// Find the lines which were selected.

textArea.text.split("\n").filter (
    function (line:String, i:Index, a:Array):Boolean {
        return selectedLineIndexes.indexOf(i) != -1;
    }
)
```

If you are actually interested in the lines in the view, taking the width of the text area into account, then it will be more complicated. In this case, the TextLineMetrics class will probably come in handy. You can obtain a reference from the IUITextField which is a protected property of the TextArea. I.e. you need to subclass TextArea to get access to this information.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/IUITextField.html

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply,

but i need some text area component of eclipse with line numbers to its left,

currently im trying to integrate 
- a list with line numbers(by getting the line count) &
next to it a text area containing text.
but thats not quite appealing.

So i was in search for any other built in/half built module.
 
i have a functionality where in  u can filter a large set of data with the range of line numbers given by user(like numeric stepper kinda input).

Any inputs will be great !

Thanks again..
Ajay